# Can Dogs in the Vineyard handle multiple healers?

Tags: healing, conflicts, dogs-in-the-vineyard

Can healing be a multi-PC conflict in DitV? The rule book only refers to a single healer, but it also doesn't explicitly state that only one PC can heal.

Answer (score 2):

Given the state of medicine at the time it's hard to imagine productively involving several disparate people in medical treatment. Even with a modern surgical team it's largely support personnel to one person who actually interacts with the body.

And the actual interaction here is what's important in the conflict, given that what gets rolled is your own Body + the healer's Acuity, since you have none of that last on account of you're at best deliriously conscious.

Other PCs can certainly help, but that's best accounted for in the relevant Relationship Dice, both yours and the healer's. You did remember to make relationships with your fellow Dogs, right?